# apex:inputchecbox selected=true is not working

Tags: visualforce

i am facing a problem, my checkboxes are not coming as checked even when i am writing `selected="true"` in `apex:inputCheckbox` tag.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#DependentTable").DataTable();
        $("#DependentTableDelete").DataTable();
    });
    var allDependentJson = new Array();
    var jsonToDeleteAddress = new Array();
</script>
<table id="AddNewDependentTable" style="width:260%; padding-top:20px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:25%">DependenNames</th>
            <th>style="width:25%">Relationship</th>
            <th style="width:25%">Add Address</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <apex:repeat value="{!toAddNewTableData}" var="DD1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <apex:outputLink value="na17.salesforce.com{!DD1.Id}" target="_blank">{!DD1.Name}</apex:outputLink><span id="DependentId" style='display:none;'>{!DD1.Id}</span></td>
                <td>{!DD1.Relationship}</td>
                <td>
                    <apex‌​:inputCheckbox onchange="select_Dependent1(this);" selected="true" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </apex:repeat>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

can anyone please help??

Thanks
Waiting for response

Comment: Your apex:inputCheckBox Tag is correct, But you have taken the id="dependentAddNewCheckBox", Are you using this id in anywhere? like Javascript or JQuery or anywhere?

Comment: actually i used it, but now it is of no use. but i tried deleting it, still checkboxes are coming unchecked

Comment: even if you removed the ID also, it is not showing checkbox as true? If you didn't remove the ID, Please try to remove it for checking. If it worked then somewhere else you are using that ID. So please remove the ID in the tag itself....

Comment: yaa i removed that but still checkboxes are coming without checked status...

Comment: <apex:inputCheckbox onchange="select_Dependent1(this);" selected="true"/> writting like this

Comment: Check if there is any Javascrpt action making the checkboxes unchecked in page load event.

Comment: No, i am not doing anything with it at page loading time

Comment: Could you please post your code....Otherwise it would be a full of doubts regarding your scenario. atleast your full javascript code or jquery code that you have used...

Comment: <table id="AddNewDependentTable" style="width:260%; padding-top:20px;" ><thead><tr><th style="width:25%">DependenNames</th><th>style="width:25%">Relationship</th><th style="width:25%">Add Address</th></tr></thead><tbody><apex:repeat value="{!toAddNewTableData}" var="DD1"><tr><td><apex:outputLink value="https://na17.salesforce.com/{!DD1.Id}" target="_blank">{!DD1.Name}</apex:outputLink><span id ="DependentId" style='display:none;'>{!DD1.Id}</span></td><td>{!DD1.Relationship}</td><td><apex:inputCheckbox onchange="select_Dependent1(this);" selected="true"/></td></tr></apex:repeat></tbody></table>

Comment: r u able to understand it?

Comment: <script> $(document).ready( function () {                  $("#DependentTable").DataTable(); $("#DependentTableDelete").DataTable(); });
     var allDependentJson=new Array();
    var jsonToDeleteAddress = new Array();

Comment: Have you tried to add value attribute of checkbox. I think inside apex:repeat, without value you cannot show the checkbox. Please verify this also

Comment: i tried in other checkboxes where i used value attribute but still its not working for me :-(  dont know what is the reason

Answer (score 0):

Its seems correct but i doubt with `id="dependentAddNewCheckBox"` which can be used in any Jquery or javascript, or rendering it through id that can cause.

Answer (score 0):

It is not because of your javascript or jquery. It is because of your apex:repeat.

What is the value that you are giving in apex:repeat?

```
<apex:repeat value={!toAddNewTableData}" var="DD1">
```

What is the return value of this **toAddNewTableData**?

What you wanna achieve by repeating?

Comment: actually i am fetching data from a object in controller that i am storing in this variable. like name of contact, his relationship